# Count per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I can’t seem to wrap my head around on how I should approach this select statement.

I have a Table called unified_assets which has the date columns firstseen and lastseen among others.

What I need to query is: All assets per month.

Obviously counting from firstseen but also exclude any rows which have a lastssen older than 3 months for that given month.

I can count all the firstseens since this is fairly straight forward.

MSSQL 16

```
SELECT YEAR(firstseen) Year, MONTH(firstseen) Month, COUNT(*) Count

FROM unified_assets

GROUP BY YEAR(firstseen), MONTH(firstseen)

ORDER BY YEAR(firstseen), MONTH(firstseen);
```

Basically what I’d need to do now is add a column adding all previous “firstseen” and subtract all “lastseen” which are older than 3 months.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

One method is to generate the months and then use correlated subqueries or `apply` for the calculation.

The following calculates the number active on the first day of the month.  It first generates all the months for 2018 -- or whatever range you are interested in:

```
with months as (
      select convert(date, '2018-01-01') as yyyymm
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, yyyymm)
      from months
      where yyyymm < '2018-01-12'
     )
select m.yyyymm,
       (select count(*)
        from unified_assets ua
        where ua.firstseen <= m.yyyymm and
              ua.lastseen >= m.yyyymm
       ) as cnt
from months m
order by m.yyyymm;
```